# Unable to execute grunt file

Tags: gruntjs

I am new bee to gruntjs , i am facing small issues. pls dont mark as -ve .Thanks people

I have the following code in Gruntfile.js

```
    module.export = funtion(grunt){
    grunt.registerTask('default',"", function(){
    grunt.log.write("Tis a  a task ");
    });
    };
```

i am trying to execute the above js file from cmd prompt as follows and it throws the following error.

```
D:\vkishore\Demo\Condo_gruntjsDemo>grunt
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: `function` is spelt wrong. won't be helping

Comment: Should also be module.exports(with an "s"), not module.export

Comment: If this is your first grunt file. You might want to use a generator to give you a starting point.

`npm install -g yo`
`npm install -g generator-gruntfile`
`yo gruntfile`

Comment: thank you every one .. @ThinkingMedia 12 hours ago - s this is my first grunt file